# Rounded image or border-radius 100%?

Tags: html, css

I have a question about rounded elements on page. For example I have a small logo which isn't rounded and I want to put it on rounded background (120x120). Is it better to make div like this:

```
border-radius: 100%;
background-color: red;
background-image: url('logo.png');
background-position: center;
```

or just create an image in for eg. Gimp?

Comment: using css sounds better since it allows changes to be made more easily later. 
Who ever is going to edit the logo image in the future may not be familiar with image editing software or perhaps they dont have an original image any more either.

Comment: It depends on your branding - if the logo is supposed to be circular anyway, it is always easier to make it that way in an image-editing program so that your branding will be consistent across all media. However, if it is just a design gimmick, stick to border-radius :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to be using the logo on a rounded background in future (e.g. Leaflets, email etc.) it may be easier to create a version of the logo in gimp or alternative, so it can be used anywhere very quickly.

If not it is really just personal preference, each has advantages and disadvantages.

**border-radius solution**

- you can remove the background on some screens if you want to with media queries
- quicker to achieve.
- background size, color and radius can easily be changed at a later stage.
- radius stays high quality/ resolution on any display.

**image solution**

- better browser support.
- Useable in future publications.

Comment: Exactly, the most important thing for me is editable background, which I think would be nice feature on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Make the div containing the image(background div) have the border radius and make the image width an height of 100% in the div.

> ```
> .background{
>  border-radius: 5px;
>  background-color: red;
>  background-image: url('logo.png');
>  background-position: center;
>  width: 100px;
>  height: 100px;
> }
>
> .img{
>  width: 100%; 
>  height: 100%;
> }
> ```

1. Give the image a border-radius as standalone

   ```
   .background{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
   }

   .img{
    border-radius: 5px;
   }
   ```